# The site doesn't know what subjective means

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, allowed-questions

I was asking a question earlier, "Can you pause the game in Starbound?"

A little popup appeared and told me off - "This question seems to be subjective and is likely to be closed"

I'd argue that the question I asked is definitively not subjective. It has a straight up 'yes, here's how' or 'no' answer, and the pop up could has mislead a less experienced user into not asking a totally acceptable answer.

[image: screenshot showing the 'subjective' popup]

What decides whether this popup comes up? Can it be changed to make its criteria more accurate?

Comment: The main trigger is the world 'you', as in "what do you think about/say about/prefer for/use for doing X?"